# ASP.NET Core RateLimit doesn't work in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, rate-limiting, rate

This is my call POST:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SuperAdminController : ControllerBase
{
    private IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public SuperAdminController(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    [Route("Add")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromBody] AddSuperAdmin addSuperAdmin)
    {
        if (addSuperAdmin.SecretKey == Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SecretKey"))
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var identityUser = new IdentityUser
                    {
                        UserName = addSuperAdmin.Email,
                        Email = addSuperAdmin.Email
                    };

                var roles = new List<string>
                {
                    "User",
                    "Admin",
                    "SuperAdmin"
                };

                var result = await _userRepository.Add(identityUser, addSuperAdmin.Password, roles);

                if (result.Count() == 0)
                {
                    return Ok("Le super admin a bien été ajouté!");
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest(Utils.FormatMesageAddUser(result));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(Utils.FormatMessageAdmin(ModelState));
            }
        }

        return BadRequest("Mauvaise clé secrète.");
    }
}
```

This is my program:

```
// AspNetCoreRateLimit
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
builder.Services.Configure<IpRateLimitOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("IpRateLimiting"));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IIpPolicyStore, MemoryCacheIpPolicyStore>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitCounterStore, MemoryCacheRateLimitCounterStore>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitConfiguration, RateLimitConfiguration>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IProcessingStrategy, AsyncKeyLockProcessingStrategy>();
builder.Services.AddInMemoryRateLimiting();
```

This is my `appsettings.json`:

```json
{
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "IpRateLimiting": {
    "EnableEndpointRateLimiting": true,
    "StackBlockedRequests": false,
    "RealIPHeader": "X-Real-IP",
    "ClientIdHeader": "X-ClientId",
    "HttpStatusCode": 429,
    "GeneralRules": [
      {
        "Endpoint": "*:/SuperAdmin/*",
        "Period": "5s",
        "Limit": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

When I call it with Postman more than 2 times in 5 seconds, I don't get a 429 error.

What have I missed?

I followed [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/rate-limiting-in-net-60#:%7E:text=is%20Rate%20Limiting%3F-,Rate%20Limiting%20is%20the%20process%20of%20limiting%20how%20much%20a,user%2FIP%20address%2Fclient). I implemented the nuget method, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you would like to set rate-limit on specific action, check my nuget package https://github.com/sa-es-ir/DotNet.RateLimit

Comment: Your nugget is perfect and it works very well! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the package [docs](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/wiki/IpRateLimitMiddleware#setup). Article (and the provided code) does not mention adding the rate limiting middleware to the pipeline:

```
var app = builder.Build();

// ...

// somewhere near the start of the pipeline
app.UseIpRateLimiting();
```

Do not forget to add `api` prefix to the endpoint definition since you have it in the route template:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

```json
{
  // ...
  "IpRateLimiting": {
    // ...
    "GeneralRules": [
      {
        "Endpoint": "*:/api/SuperAdmin/*",
        "Period": "5s",
        "Limit": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm still not getting 429 error

Comment: @mathdx that is because you have missed `api` in the endpoint definition, try `"Endpoint": "*:/api/SuperAdmin/*"` (works for me with your copy-pasted setup + `UseIpRateLimiting`)

Comment: @mathdx also note that since .NET 7 there are [build-in ratelimiting capabilities in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-7.0?view=aspnetcore-7.0#rate-limiting-middleware-in-aspnet-core), so if you can upgrade you can set it up without 3rd-party components.